# css stylesheet as a component parameter / have distinct stylesheets for a single component

Tags: css, angular

I have a dropdown menu component that I use in my website and I want to reuse it on the very same website but with a different styling. Is it possible to load a different stylesheet?

Comment: You can add multiple stylesheets via `styleUrls` array (`styleUrls: ['style1.css', 'style2.css']`) and combine that with different classes on your component to only apply the correct styles

Comment: Yeah I just thought about that, I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cyrix suggested, I used a class in my component tag :

```
<dropdown-menu class="blue-theme"></dropdown-menu>
```

then I could override any of the existing rules in dropdown-menu.component.css with `:host()` :

```
span { background-color: white; } /* existing */
:host(.blue-theme) span { background-color: blue; } /* overrided */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to achieve this functionality.For 1st use case set booleanVar1 = true and booleanVar2 = false, for 2nd use case set booleanVar1 = false and booleanVar2 = true.

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': booleanVar1, 'class2': booleanVar2}"
```